# Regex to remove characters and pick between numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have a following string, I need to apply regex using C#:

```
2018-12-26P18:07:05:07
```

I need to pick the 18 and 07 only. So the result I need is 1807

I tried

```
\d+-\d+-\d+P
```

This removes for me `2018-12-26P`. Now how do I remove `:` and then pick only `1807`

Comment: A single regex can't match *and* replace at once like that. What language are implementing this in?

Comment: Trivially, `^.*?(\d+):(\d+).*$` works. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrK4Bn/1/) (Alternatively, `^.*P(\d+):(\d+).*$`) But whether that is useful to you is entirely dependent on the language.

Comment: I'm implementing in C#

Comment: @dawg, this doesn't work. The result i'm getting is empty. I'm trying it like this: `var time = Regex.Replace("2018-12-26T18:07:05:07", @"^.*?(\d+):(\d+).*$", ""); `

Comment: @user726720 you can use this https://regex101.com/r/LRAc1h/2/

Comment: @CodeManiac: The result in C# is `2018-12-26T18:07:05:`

Comment: @user726720 You should use match.groups!

Comment: @BladeMight: can you give an example.

Comment: @user726720 this will match `18` and `07`. use match and just combine them you will get your output. `2018-12-26T18:07:05:` how come `T` appear here ?

Comment: @user726720 See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple Regular Expressions groups usage:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RE {
    class TEST {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Your string
            var str = "2018-12-26P18:07:05:07";
            // Regex to match 18 and 07 to 1 and second group.
            var re = new Regex(@"\d+-\d+-\d+[A-z](\d+):(\d+)");
            // Execute regex over string, and get our matched groups
            var match = re.Match(str);
            // Write the groups.
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just left office will test it tomorrow, and get back to you. Did a quick test on online regex tester and it looks good. Will test it on C# soon. THANKS

Comment: @user726720 if it solves your problem, accept as answer, on the left side of answer there will be gray checkmark ✓, press it so it will accept this answer as answer to this question.

Comment: Yes that was perfect